# Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::validator does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

I am trying to do registration of multi-user in my registration controller and used the following code and checked. But it shows me error:

**Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::validator does not exist.**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Admin;
use App\Manager;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
        $this->middleware('guest:manager');
    }

    protected function createAdmin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $admin = Admin::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
        return redirect()->intended('login/admin');
    }

    protected function createManager(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $manager = Manager::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
        return redirect()->intended('login/manager');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a `function validator()` in your `RegisterController` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `validator()` function like follow:

```php
protected function validator(array $data, $table)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:'.$table],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

then you can make validation like so:

```
$this->validator($request->all(), 'table_name')->validate();
```

change **table_name** with corresponding name.

Comment: thanks it works! However I am encountering another problem when doing multi-auth. Now when i submit the registration it shows me: 
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bvend.users' doesn't exist.

Though i have no users table, instead I have admins table

Comment: @WahidSherief change `'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],` to `'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:admins'],`

Comment: @WahidSherief You're getting this error because validator is looking for `users` table's email column to check for email if it already exists